# Sort array of strings by portion of each string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array of strings by a portion of each string.

Here is my list:

```
[
    "5,758,ZUMBA,13:00:00",
    "3,541,Vinyasa level 2/3,10:30:00",
    "3,559,Mat Pilates,18:30:00"
]
```

How can I sort it by the second value? The order I need is

```
541, 559, 758
```

Comment: 1) Where are your attempts? 2) You cannot sort JSON. JSON is a string representing serialized data. You must parse the JSON into an actual data structure, and this in a language/environment/platform. Where parsing the JSON? The answer to your question of how to sort data hinges on your answer to that question. 3) Who is responsible for the formatting of that data? There's not a lot of point in using JSON if you're just going to pack it full of magic strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom sort function:

```js
var array = ["5,758,ZUMBA,13:00:00","3,541,Vinyasa level 2/3,10:30:00","3,559,Mat Pilates,18:30:00"];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    
    var c = a.split(',')[1];
    var d = b.split(',')[1];
    
    if (c < d) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (c > d) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});

console.log(array);
```